# Views, Joins, Locks and Order By

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking, view

I created a view using

```
CREATE VIEW NewView AS
WITH TableA AS
(
    SELECT * FROM RealTableA WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE (Something1)
)
,
TableB AS
(
    SELECT * FROM RealTableB WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) WHERE (Something2)
)
SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON (TableA.ID = TableB.RefID)
```

and everything is working smoothly - two processes running at the same time selecting from the view will select different records from it. The problem is that now I want  to use an `ORDER BY` clause, and even though I have used

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SOMEINDEX ON RealTableB ( Field1 ASC , Field2 ASC ) INCLUDE ( RefID )
```

everything brakes down when I use

`SELECT TOP (@Something) * FROM NewView ORDER BY Field1 ASC , Field2 ASC`,

I mean, Process1 selects the first `@Something` results correctly, but Process2 returns nothing, indicating a probable table lock (but why, if I have an index by the fields I am ordering by?). However, if I remove the `ORDER BY` clause it works nicely, but without the desired order. I tried the `WITH ( INDEX ( IX_SOMEINDEX ) )` within the CTE, but it didn't work. I really need to make this work as soon as possible. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use SELECT *. If you ask for all columns a table scan (often shown as clustered index scan) will happen. One of your tables has all rows locked because of this.

Change the view to this and put the hints outside. Then index it.

```
CREATE VIEW NewView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    --real column list
FROM 
   RealTableA
   INNER JOIN
    TableB ON (TableA.ID = TableB.RefID)
WHERE
   (Something1) AND  (Something2)
```

If this fails (eg you have a LOB column based on previous questions), you need to post 100% accurate code and 100% accurate data and 100& accurate queries. We can't help with sanitised code usually.

Comment: So what can be a solution to this problem? Selecting only one column in the last select yields the same result.

Comment: Don't use SELECT *. This allows WITH SCHEMABINDING in the view. Which means the view can be indexed. Add the text plan (not XML) please

Comment: I don't have SQL Server Profiler available. Sorry for that... I tried using an indexed view but I ended up having a complete mess and still no results...

Comment: SET SHOWPLAN TEXT ON: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176058.aspx Did you stop using SELECT * ?

Comment: Yes, I did... But still, the results are the same. I will post the execution plan now.